# Autocomplete from object instead of array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to use [Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples) from Angular Material.

Their data is `options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];`, but instead of that I have an object.

This is how I get the data from the object, which is in *currencies.json*:

```js
list(): Observable<Currencies> {
  return this._http.get('./assets/currencies.json') as unknown as Observable<Currencies>;
}
```

```js
public currencies$ = this.getAllCurrencies();

getAllCurrencies(): Observable<Currencies> {
  return this._currencyService.list();
}
```

Now this is how I tried to bind the autocomplete:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="currencies$ | async">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Currency</mat-label>
      <input id="currency" type="text" matInput placeholder="Select a currency. E.g. USD" [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="currency">
      <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let currency of currencies$ | keyvalue" [value]="currency.key">
          {{currency.key}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

```js
this.currencies$ = this.formMain.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(value => this.currencies$.subscribe(data => data.currency.includes((value.toString().toUpperCase() || '')))),
);
```

But then I get this error:

> TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable'.   Property 'currency' is missing in type
> 'Subscription' but required in type 'Currencies'.

How can I fix this?

---

I have also tried it this way:

```js
currencies?: Observable<string[]>;

this.currencies = this.formMain.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(value => this.currencies$.subscribe(data => data.currency.includes((value.toString().toUpperCase() || '')))),
);
```

but then I get this error:

> TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable<string[]>'.   Type 'Subscription' is missing the following
> properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28
> more.

Also tried it without `subscribe()`:

```js
this.formMain.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(value => [this.currencies$].filter(currency => currency.includes(value)))
);
```

But then I get the error:

> TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type
> 'Observable'.

[This is my code on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q9ms62-bqbenp?file=src/app/autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts) and [this is the official code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qz348l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts) of Angular Material on StackBlitz.
I want the result to be exactly the same as the official code but with my own data.

Comment: Maybe you need to use the `async` pipe on `currencies$` before you use the `keyvalue` pipe?

Comment: @R.Richards but then I still get the same error. I get that error even without HTML.

Comment: Calling `subscribe()` on an observable from within a `map()` operator is undoubtedly the wrong thing to do. I think you need to reevaluate where your data is and what you need to do with it.

Comment: @JeffMercado I see. I have tried it without `subscribe()` but then I get an error. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**, you use wrong interface for your object.

The code

```
export interface Currencies {
  currency: string;
}
```

means that your data should be smth like:

```
{
  currency: 'some string'
}
```

In case of your object you can use:

```
export type Currencies = Record<string, string>;
```

**Secondly**, you don't have to cast your http call:

```
this._http.get('./assets/currencies.json') as unknown as Observable<Currencies>;
```

just use generic version of `http.get<T>` method:

```
this._http.get<Currencies>('./assets/currencies.json')
               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Third**, you should be using `[formControl]` binding in your stackblitz because you don't have a wrapper with `formGroup`:

```
formControlName="currency" => [formControl]="myControl"
```

Finally, while constructing `currencies$` observable you need to continue work with `Observable` by using `switchMap` instead of `map` rxjs operator:

```
currencies$ = this._currencyService.list().pipe(
  switchMap((currencies) => {
    return this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((query) =>
        Object.fromEntries(
          Object.entries(currencies).filter(([key]) =>
            key.includes(query.toUpperCase())
          )
        )
      )
    );
  })
);
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q9ms62-hzcddo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcurrencies.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts)**

Comment: Thank you yurzui! Your code works like a charm on StackBlitz but in my application, I get the following error in HTML on `*ngFor="let currency of currencies | keyvalue"`:  _Argument type ObservedValueOf<Observable<{[p: string]: string}>> is not assignable to parameter type ReadonlyMap<unknown, unknown>_ ... I am using Angular 13.3.3 and TypeScript 4.7.2.

Comment: There must be something wrong with `map((query) => ...`. If I remove that method, the error disappears. With `map()` the type of `currencies$` is ` Observable<{[p: string]: string}>` and without it, it's ` Observable<any>`.

Comment: If you download the project on StackBlitz, you will probably get the same error. Well, I have now changed it to `map((query): any => ...` and now the error is gone.